# Extract substring before = sign using awk

Tags: regex, awk

Say I have some file with a bunch of lines in the form

```
someString=someMoreCharacters
anotherString.blah=foo=bar
blah.blah.blah=foo.bar.=foobar
```

Desired output

```
someString
anotherString.blah
blah.blah.blah
```

I want to use awk to extract the substring that starts at the beginning of the line and goes up until, but not including the *first* equals sign. I want to be able to pipe this output to xargs.

Comment: sed's greediness makes this a quick fix, `sed 's/=.*//'`, although I've never done anything with awk.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Awk:

```
awk '{sub(/=.*/, ""); print}' filename
```

But, I think Rob's solution is easier:

```
sed 's/=.*//' filename
```